# Using different escaping methods

Tags: magento2, template, security

I noticed class `vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php` which contains a few useful security methods used inside (mainly) templates. Some of them are quite common (`escapeHtml()`), but some of them are hard to encounter.

1. What method and `escapeXssInUrl()` really does?
2. In case of method `escapeJsQuote()` - what is the place where these quotes can be found? Only inline `js` in templates?
3. Does anyone has some clear explanation when all methods should be used (practical examples)?
4. What is a difference between `escapeUrl()` and `escapeXssInUrl()` and if second one grants us better security, why not always use second one instead escaping only html chars?
5. `escapeQuote()` should be used for example for echoing some variable in situation like this `<div value="<?php echo`[here?]`$value?>"></div>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Most of the functions for Security measures against XSS attacks.

`escapeXssInUrl()` Method Remove `javascript:`, `vbscript:`, `data:` words from url and used like

```
echo $block->escapeXssInUrl($block->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $block->getAnchorTextHtml()
```

Magento 1 You can escape the quotes in javascript using `$this->jsQuoteEscape ($item->getName());` Mahento 2 you can do the same using `escapeJsQuote`

`escapeUrl()` actually leverages htmlspecialchars with the recommended parameters to escape HTML: `$result = htmlspecialchars($result, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);`

You can find more information by Magento 2 [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-security.html).

Comment: Can you tell the difference between `escapeUrl()` and `escapeXssInUr()l`?

It is worth noticing that `The upcoming release of Magento 2.2 will deprecate these functions.

Please check back on this page after the 2.2 release for updated documentation on new escape functions.`

Answer (score 3):

There is a helpful entry in the DevDocs on template security:
[Security measures against XSS attacks](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-security.html)

Re `escapeXssInUrl`: The function `escapeUrl` calls `escapeXssInUrl` internally plus `escapeHtml` afterwards. Also Magento uses `escapeUrl` internally.

Make sure to check out the new escaping functions once Magento 2.2. is out as there will be new ones coming:

> The upcoming release of Magento 2.2 will deprecate these functions.
>
> Please check back on this page after the 2.2 release for updated
>   documentation on new escape functions.

And you might as well be interested to check out my presentation about this here: [Secure input and output handling - Meet Magento Romania 2016](http://www.slideshare.net/avoelkl/secure-input-and-output-handling-meet-magento-romania-2016-67787417)

Comment: actually I have watched your training on Mage Titans Italy and I wanted to clarify some information and that was one of the reason of question :)!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBSr5Esb-8M
That is what I have noticed 

That's what I also noticed about `escapeXssInUrl()` - so should I use `escapeUrl()` insted?

'Eav Backedn validation rules' - I guess they are just use automatically and I am already using them? Or should that implement them in places inputs ar added?

Comment: I think it's better to use `escapeUrl` than `escapeXssInUrl` as this is called internally: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/1ade3b769a937f19682bbbe4e51b6c956147952f/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Escaper.php#L206

Comment: I haven't noticed that - that is right!